# sql select for post_title and a term name

Tags: posts, terms, title

I'm having trouble trying to think out this `SQL` select I need to write; here's the gist:  I'm programmatically creating posts by importing an excel file, so I'm in 100% sure of post titles, etc, since I'm creating those that aren't found.  I've got a few bits of data that I'm using for a lookup of a post before I create a new post:  the post_title, that it is a post_type of 'team', and looking up it's term name in a 'term_type' taxonomy (ie 'College').

Here's the $args for a normal simplified taxonomy wp_query lookup:

```
$args = array('post_type'=>'team', 'post_title'=>$teamName, 'post_status'=>'publish', 'team_type'=>$type);
```

The trouble is of course that you can't do a lookup in this way with a post_title.  Now I could create the select for that but I'm having trouble with the lookup of the joins -- the name in the terms, and with that the term_id to term_taxonomy_id in term_relationships giving me the object_id...  I'm sure it's just lack of sleep.

I'll probably just do a simple 'get_term_by' before I try my copy of the query that failed with a post_title lookup in addition, but my geek need to do it all in one go is pushing me to know the 'correct' way.